# How to tell if a numbers in a list are going in order

Tags: c#, list

I want to start off by saying I'm not trying to be spoon fed, this is an exercise for a class I'm currently taking but I cannot figure out what to do for the life of me. We have to have a user input 5 numbers, and print out whether the numbers are going in order or not. I haven't created the input section yet but that's just because I want to get the figuring out if the numbers are in order yet down first. I know what's wrong with the code and why it won't compile, I'm going to display my code, I'll explain what's wrong, my problem is I don't know how to fix it.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var numberList = new List<int>() { 5, 12 };
        var isConsecutive = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberList.Count; i++) {
            var first = numberList[i];
            int second = numberList[i + 1];

            if (!(first < second)) {
                isConsecutive = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isConsecutive) {
            Console.WriteLine("Not Consecutive");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Is Consecutive");
        }

    }
}
```

I know that I can't do

```
numberList[i + 1];
```

because that's trying to find a number that doesn't exist. I just can't find a way around this.

Comment: What error you are getting when you compile the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think about why that code is failing.  You are trying to compare the last element in the list to the next element which doesn't exist.  What would that mean for determining if the list is in order? You have already compared the last element with the element before, so there is no need for your last element to be included as the first element in a compare in your loop.

So you just need to change your for loop to exclude the last element in the list.  You will still be comparing every element that has a following element to ensure the following element is not lower or equal:

```
//  "numberList.Count - 1" so that you stop before the last element
for (int i = 0; i < numberList.Count - 1; i++) {
```

Another option would be to start at element 1 and go to the last element and ensure that they are not lower than or equal to the previous element:

```
// start at 1 so you compare all the other elements with the element before
for (int i = 1; i < numberList.Count; i++) {
    var first = numberList[i - 1];
    int second = numberList[i];
    if (!(first < second)) {
        isConsecutive = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to reduce the iteration of your loop by one.  So instead of

```
i < numberList.count
```

you'll want to make that

```
i < numberList.count - 1
```

because you're already accounting for two places in numberList by using [i + 1].
Another option would be to start the loop with

```
int i = 1
```

and reference numberList.count, but for the first position, use

```
numberList[i - 1]
```